# Equivalent sql server statement for c# expression

Tags: c#, sql-server

Wanted to know what is the equivalent sql server statement for below c# expression,

```
 (a1 != "abc" || a2 != "abcdefg") && false
```

Comment: even though result is `false` right??

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE (a1 <> 'abc' OR a2 <> 'abcdefg') AND 1 = 2`

But you can also use `!=` in SQL-Server (although not ANSI standard)

> i want to add it in a select clause not in where

```
SELECT ConditionTrue = CASE WHEN (a1 <> 'abc' OR a2 <> 'abcdefg') AND 1 = 2
                       THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM dbo.TableName
```

It's worth noting that the condition is never true(`Yes`) because of `AND 1 = 2`(same as C# version).

Comment: i want to add it in a select clause not in where

Comment: @Prasu: then replace `where` with `select`, for example with a `SELECT CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: SQL is declarative rather than procedural so it doesn't have short-circuit versions of `AND` and `OR` logical operators. The T-SQL code in this answer is equivalent to `(a1 != "abc" | a2 != "abcdefg") & false`. The result is logically the same, though, barring `NULL` values.

Comment: select columnB, (a1 <> 'abc' or a2 <> 'abcdefg' ) and 0  from temptable, this giving me error

Comment: @Prasu: What you exptect from this? If you append `false` or `1=2` the result will always be `false`. However, edited my answer to show you how

Comment: i have just shown the example , actual expression would be  (a1 != "abc" || a2 != "abcdefg") && IsDeleted. Here IsDeleted is a bool flag

Comment: So if i simply write select (a1 <> 'abc' OR a2 <> 'abcdefg') AND Isdeleted , then its showing error.

Comment: You haven't tried what I've shown in my answer. Replace 1=2 with IsDeleted